# Spring boot and RabbitMQ: Failed to connect to reactor.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient

Tags: java, spring, websocket, rabbitmq, broker

I've setup my spring boot application as follows:

**application.properties**:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

**WebSocketConfig.java** :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");


    }
}
```

**RabbiMQ configuration**: (installed on Windows 7)

```
Protocol    Bound to    Port
amqp        127.0.0.1   5672
clustering  ::          25672
http        0.0.0.0     15672
http        ::          15672
```

When i start the application i recive this error:

```
Failed to connect to reactor.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient
```

This happens even if i set the properties in the configuration class.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable stomp broker on RabbitMQ using:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stomp
```

Also, the port for STOMP is 61613, not 5672.

Comment: saved our day/life/etc